# 'Edge of time' meaning of phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of *at the edge of time* in the following sentence?

> At times they spent hours chatting in the office, while the house seemed suspended at the **edge of time**.

Comment: I don't think *edge of time* is an idiom. Here it seems like a literary use of nonce phrase.

Answer (score 1):

**Edge**:

- a line or border at which a surface terminates.

Here *edge of time* is used in a figurative way to refer to *the far end of time* suggesting that they were *so immersed in their chatting* in office that the house appeared to be as something very far away from their reality. The author is probably suggesting that they were so absorbed by their chat that they almost lost touch with they world.

Answer (score 0):

They were lost in their own world and time itself was irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

It's metaphorical, suggesting a place where time no longer flows.